# take nsdictionary and nsstring values from a nsdictionary

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a function that returns an `NSDictionary` named data. It contains 2 objects: a `NSDictionary` object with the key `currency_data` and an `NSString` object with the key `time`.

I want to pass :

- the string value with the key `time` to a new `NSString` object
- the `NSDictionary` object with the key `currency_data` to a `NSMutableDictionary` variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: i try to pass them like this

`NSMutableDictionary *cur_data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[data objectForKey:@"currency_data"]];
   
NSString *time = [data valueForKey:@"time"];`
But when i nslog it, it returns nul

Comment: If you need to pass multiple values, encapsulate and then pass the object.

Comment: what do you mean? Can i have a small example please?

Comment: Have you tried using `retain`? E.g. `[cur_data setValue:[currency_data retain] forKey:@"currency_data"];`

Comment: What do you get id you log [data objectForKey:@"currency_data"]. The code you posted should work if that expression returns a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you use ARC. With ARC your example should work, without ARC you need to retain at least the string values.

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [foo data];
NSMutableDictionary *currency_dict= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dataDict[@"currency_data"]];
NSString *time = [data[@"time"] retain];
```

What [anoop-vaidy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395941/anoop-vaidya) meant is I think, if you need a mutable dictionary, create that in the data call directly and pass it out. Another note: You can use your knowledge of you data structure in a better way. Instead of building a dictionary with 2 keys, use the first value ( the time string) as the key and the second (the currency dict) as the value. You can access values and keys in dictionaries quite easily

```
NSArray *value = dict.allValues;
NSArray *keys = dict.allKeys;
```